Unable to focus on second textinput or rthe submit button
I am unable to focus on second textinput in this, first one works fine. Also the submit button isn't pressable. The second input and submit button starts working fine after i input something in first input component.
I am using reanimated for animating the bottom container.
 const {width, height} = useWindowDimensions();
 const isKeyboardOpen = useKeyboardStatus();
 const offsetY = useSharedValue(0);
 const Available_Height = height - 55;
 const Banner_Height = Available_Height * 0.4;
 const AnimateTo = Banner_Height - 55 + 16;
 const animatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
   return {
     transform: [{translateY: offsetY.value}],
   };
 });

 useEffect(() => {
   if (isKeyboardOpen) {
     offsetY.value = withTiming(-AnimateTo, {
       duration: 250,
     });
   } else {
     offsetY.value = withTiming(0, {duration: 250});
   }
 }, [isKeyboardOpen]);

 return (
   <Wrapper navHeading={'Login'} canGoBack={false}>
     <ViewComponent
       backgroundColor={SemanticColors.MAIN_FOREGROUND}
       style={{flex: 1}}>
       <ViewComponent backgroundColor={SemanticColors.MAIN_FOREGROUND}>
         <AuthSVG width={width} height={Banner_Height} />
       </ViewComponent>
       <ReanimatedBox
         backgroundColor={SemanticColors.MAIN_BACKGROUND}
         style={[
           {
             borderTopRightRadius: 14,
             borderTopLeftRadius: 14,
             padding: 16,
             height: Available_Height - Banner_Height,
             justifyContent: 'space-between',
           },
           animatedStyles,
         ]}>
         <ViewComponent>
           <InputField
             placeholder="Email"
             onFocus={() => {
               console.log('focused 1');
             }}
           />
           <InputField
             placeholder="Password"
             onFocus={() => {
               console.log('focused 2');
             }}
           />
         </ViewComponent>
         <ViewComponent marginBottom={Spacings.S}>
           <CustomButton
             onPress={() => {}}
             title={'Next'}
             btnType={BtnTypes.PRIMARY}
           />
         </ViewComponent>
       </ReanimatedBox>
     </ViewComponent>
   </Wrapper>
 );
};
export default Login;

And animated box is made using this code:
import {
  BackgroundColorProps,
  BorderProps,
  LayoutProps,
  PositionProps,
  ShadowProps,
  SpacingProps,
  SpacingShorthandProps,
  backgroundColor,
  createRestyleComponent,
  spacing,
  spacingShorthand,
  layout,
  border,
  shadow,
} from '@shopify/restyle';
import {Theme} from '@themes/Themes';
import {ViewProps} from 'react-native';
import Animated, {AnimatedProps} from 'react-native-reanimated';

export type ReanimatedBoxProps = BackgroundColorProps<Theme> &
  SpacingProps<Theme> &
  LayoutProps<Theme> &
  BorderProps<Theme> &
  SpacingShorthandProps<Theme> &
  PositionProps<Theme> &
  ShadowProps<Theme> &
  AnimatedProps<ViewProps>;

const ReanimatedBox = createRestyleComponent<ReanimatedBoxProps, Theme>(
  [backgroundColor, spacing, spacingShorthand, layout, border, shadow],
  Animated.View,
);

export default ReanimatedBox;

  value,
  label,
  icon,
  iconPosition,
  error,
  secureTextEntry,
  editable,
  defaultValue,
  onSubmitEditing,
  keyboardType,
  rightIcon,
  style,
  placeholder,
  onIconPress,
  onChange,
  onBlur,
  onFocus,
}: InputFieldProps) => {
  const theme = useTheme<ThemeType>();
  const currentTheme = useAppSelector(state => state.theme.currentTheme);

  const wrapperStyle: StyleProp<ViewStyle> = {
    flexDirection: icon
      ? iconPosition === 'left'
        ? 'row'
        : 'row-reverse'
      : 'row',
    alignItems: icon ? 'center' : 'center',
  };

  return (
    <ViewComponent
      style={styles.inputContainer}
      backgroundColor={SemanticColors.MAIN_BACKGROUND}>
      {!!label && (
        <TextComponent color={SemanticColors.MAIN_FOREGROUND}>
          {label}
        </TextComponent>
      )}
      <ViewComponent
        borderColor={
          error ? SemanticColors.ERROR_COLOR : SemanticColors.INPUT_PRIMARY
        }
        backgroundColor={SemanticColors.MAIN_BACKGROUND}
        style={[styles.wrapper, wrapperStyle]}>
        {!!icon && (
          <ViewComponent>
            <ViewComponent>{icon}</ViewComponent>
          </ViewComponent>
        )}
        <TextInput
          style={[
            styles.textInput,
            style,
            {color: theme.colors.primaryButtonText},
          ]}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          onChangeText={onChange}
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          value={value}
          onFocus={onFocus}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          placeholderTextColor={
            currentTheme === ThemeTypes.LIGHT
              ? theme.colors.secondaryText
              : theme.colors.inputPrimary
          }
          editable={editable}
          selectTextOnFocus={editable}
          onEndEditing={onSubmitEditing}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
        />
        {!!rightIcon && (
          <Pressable
            onPress={onIconPress}
            style={{
              height: '100%',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
            <ViewComponent style={{marginHorizontal: 8}}>
              {rightIcon}
            </ViewComponent>
          </Pressable>
        )}
      </ViewComponent>
      {!!error && (
        <TextComponent style={{color: theme.colors.error}}>
          {error}
        </TextComponent>
      )}
    </ViewComponent>
  );
};

export default memo(InputField)

